# javascript zoom and drag multiple images within div. got some code but cant get to an end

Tags: javascript, zooming, move, drag, pan

i have this code https://jsfiddle.net/j8kLz6wm/1/

when i add another image it does not work

```
 <img ondragstart="return false" id="drag-img" src="http://www.patsoy.com/p/2015/09/geometric-patterns-f03phtdx.jpg" />
```

and it nicely does what i need,

but i cannot get my head around how to have multiple images in this div which all can be moved freely.

i want to be able to make collages with multiple images.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I've just gone with your codebase. I think the image url is wrong.
it working well with this url https://via.placeholder.com/150.
I think you have to check your image url.

You can use classname instead of id to handle this issue.

```
    <div id="container">
      <img ondragstart="return false" class="drag-img" src="http://www.patsoy.com/p/2015/09/geometric-patterns-f03phtdx.jpg" />
      <img ondragstart="return false" class="drag-img" src="http://www.patsoy.com/p/2015/09/geometric-patterns-f03phtdx.jpg" />
    </div>
```

And add addEventListener to each items

```
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName('drag-img');
  for (let item of items) {
    item.addEventListener(event_start, start_drag);
  }
```

here is the codebase.  https://jsfiddle.net/jsdev778/5myvsxzw/21

Hope this help you.

Comment: yes, with one image it works nice, but multiple images dont :(

Comment: please check this url. https://jsfiddle.net/jsdev778/5myvsxzw/21/

Comment: wow this is beautiful. i tried with class but your way of putting items through a loop could not do that.

Comment: now i gotta figure out how to get these zoomin zoomout buttons to work as they are also on the div-id

Comment: I didn't get you what you couldn't, just checked on my side and it works, could you elaborate on it?

Comment: oh, I see, zoomin, zoomout issue, it's like you can go in same way.

Comment: you think ontouch change element id to drag-img so the zoom buttons correspond to the touched image?

Comment: got your question. definitely, you know, you can't deal with this issue only with id, you can use data-attributes for identifying the specific item which touched

Comment: thanks a lot, i got it by using a hidden form: https://jsfiddle.net/3bmptwzk/
i upvoted you ofcourse, but it doesnt show up since i am new user